# scala polymorphic type signatures with Ordering and ClassTag

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism

I need help understanding this type signature:

```
def func[A : Ordering : ClassTag](a: A) = ???
```

I've come up with dummy examples using the type signature above...  and also the type signature I'm more familiar with, that I believe is the close to the same thing based on my dummy example, but I can also come up with a toy example where they are clearly not the same.

These two seem similar:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

// type signature in question
def func1[A : Ordering : ClassTag](elems: A*) = 
  Array[A](elems: _*).sorted

// my typical type signature
def func2[A <% Ordered[A]](elems: A*)(implicit c: ClassTag[A]) = 
  Array[A](elems: _*).sorted
```

Example use:

```
class BB(val i: Int) extends Ordered[BB] {
  def compare(that: BB): Int = that.i - i
  override def toString = s"BB(${i})"
}

func1(new BB(33), new BB(100), new BB(-1))
func2(new BB(33), new BB(100), new BB(-1))
```

Output for each is:

```
Array[BB] = Array(BB(100), BB(33), BB(-1))
```

The one edge case I can come up with where they differ...  indicating one is not simply syntactic sugar for the other...  is the following, where the function has an implicit order for a class that differs from the class's natural sort order.

This example (below) works fine, and `implicit val ordering` overrides class BB's natural sort order as I (kind of) expected.

```
def func3[A <% Ordered[A] : ClassTag](elems: A*) = {
  // opposite order defined in class BB
  implicit val ordering: Ordering[A] = 
    Ordering.by{ case bb: BB => bb.i }  

  Array[A](elems: _*).sorted
}
```

This version (below) give me an error...

```
def func3[A : Ordering : ClassTag](elems: A*) = {
  // opposite order defined in class BB
  implicit val ordering: Ordering[A] = 
    Ordering.by{ case bb: BB => bb.i }  

  Array[A](elems: _*).sorted
}
```

> error:  ambiguous implicit values: both value evidence$1 of type Ordering[A]
>   and value ordering of type Ordering[A] match expected type
>   scala.math.Ordering[A]

So based on this...  I'm guessing `: Ordering` sort of converts `Ordered[BB]` into an `implicit val ordering`...  or something like that?  Are there deeper differences that my toy examples fail to reveal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `:` after a type parameter is syntactic sugar for the declaration of implicit parameters. In this case this means that

```
def func1[A: Ordering: ClassTag](elems: A*) = Array[A](elems: _*).sorted
```

is the same as

```
def func1[A](elems: A*)(implicit ordering: Ordering[A], classTag: ClassTag[A]) = Array[A](elems: _*).sorted
```

On the other hand `func2` is declaring a view bound (`<%`) from `A` to `Ordered`. Knowing this the compiler can summon a `Ordering[Ordered]` that is passed to the `sorted` method

The reason why the latest version of `fun3` is not compiling is because you are providing 2 implicit `Ordering[A]` in the scope: the one declared as an implicit parameter of `fun3` and the implicit val `ordering`. The compiler doesn't know which one to choose and it complains about it, you should remove one of them to fix it.

Anyway, it is not a good idea to introduce code about specific types in the implementation of these functions. That pattern matching in the creation of the val `ordering` will fail for any type that is not `BB`.

If your goal is to define a specific `Ordering[BB]` you can do that in the companion object of BB and then load it in the implicit scope of the caller function like this

```
class BB(val i: Int) {
  override def toString: String = s"BB(${i})"
}

object BB {
  implicit val ordering = Ordering.by[BB, Int](_.i)
  val reverseOrdering = Ordering.by[BB, Int](-_.i)
}
```

Then when you try to order an BB it will pick the implicit ordering by default, but you could always overwrite it by doing

```
implicit val ord = BB.reverseOrdering
Seq[BB]().sorted
```